# How to implement long press key event for stm32f429i discovery board using keil?

Tags: button, stm32, stm32f4discovery, long-press

I interfaced a keypad to stm32f429i board and am able to display respective button of keypad on LCD screen of board. Short press is working fine but I have no idea how to implement long press key event. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: As [suggested by PeterJ_01](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef4.html), using a Timer interrupt is the most elegant way. Do not use the GPIO interrupt for buttons!**

If you are using the [Hardware Abstraction Layer (**HAL**)](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef4.html) Library, you can do something like this inside your GPIO interrupt:

```c
static int timestamp_pressed = -1;  // -1 means not pressed

if (timestamp_pressed == -1) {
    // user just pressed the button
    timestamp_pressed = HAL_GetTick();  // milliseconds since startup
} else if (HAL_GetTick() - timestamp_pressed > 2000) {
    // 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds are over
    // << your code

    timestamp_pressed = -1;
}
```

If you are not using HAL and don't want to use a regular timer interrupt (from TIM1, TIM2, TIM3, ...) you can consider using the SysTick timer (with an interrupt or without). There is plenty information about it in the internet ;)

Comment: using EXTI interrupts for the buttons is the huge mistake and should be avoided.

Comment: Why is that so? Because of contact bounce? (If so, couldn't that be resolved in a similar way as I proposed - or is that considered bad style?)

Comment: because you need to block the program execution in the interrupt for the time of the debouncing. Timer interrupts should be used for it.

Comment: I agree that blocking the program in the interrupt is a terrible thing to do. However, if you look at the code i suggested, wouldn't that be fine?

Comment: Ooh i see. The contact bounce would practically block the program because of the multiple interrupts. If your interrupt routine is actively waiting doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not obvious could you please explain a little?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you need to use the timer interrupt. Here is the link and the library:

https://www.diymat.co.uk/arm-three-function-click-double-and-long-click-button-library-timer-interrupt-driven/

Comment: Your link doesn't open for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

An implementation inspired from STM32F746G discovery board example.

```
if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Push_GPIO_Port,Push_Pin) != RESET)
  {

      HAL_Delay(10);//debounce
      timestamp_butpressed = HAL_GetTick();
      while (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Push_GPIO_Port,Push_Pin) != RESET);
      timestamp_butreleased = HAL_GetTick();

      //Is button pressed enouph to run the program?
      if(timestamp_butreleased>timestamp_butpressed?//This condition prevent max value to cause problem
              ((timestamp_butreleased-timestamp_butpressed)>2000)://normal condition
              ((4294967295-timestamp_butpressed)+timestamp_butreleased)>2000)//glitchy conditioin handle
      {
          //application runs here or flag handling heppens here
      }

  }
```

Another triky implementation (long press triggers as it reaches required time):

```
if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Push_GPIO_Port,Push_Pin) != RESET)
{
 HAL_Delay(10);
 while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Push_GPIO_Port,Push_Pin) == RESET)
 {
   HAL_Delay(5);
   i++
   if(i==100)break;
 }
 if(i<100)
 {
 short pressed
 }
 else
 {
 long pressed
 }
}
```

A functional implementation:

```
uint8_t pushbot(GPIO_TypeDef *GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{

    if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOx,GPIO_Pin) != RESET)
      {
            uint32_t timestamp_butpressed=0;
            uint32_t timestamp_butreleased=0;
          HAL_Delay(10);//debounce
          timestamp_butpressed = HAL_GetTick();
          while (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOx, GPIO_Pin) != RESET);
          timestamp_butreleased = HAL_GetTick();

          //Is button pressed enouph to run the program?
          if(timestamp_butreleased>timestamp_butpressed?//This condition prevent max value to cause problem
                  ((timestamp_butreleased-timestamp_butpressed)>1000)://normal condition
                  ((4294967295-timestamp_butpressed)+timestamp_butreleased)>1000)//glitchy conditioin handle
              {
              return 2;// long pressed
              }
          else
          {
              return 1;// short pressed
          }
      }
    else
    {
        return 0;// not pressed
    }

}
```